# Found an Unknown Relational Diagram Symbol in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer (the table modeling part) and I have found a symbol that I can't seem to be able to find an explanation for anywhere online:

[image]

I have been searching for a while now, and I'm at a total loss. I'm not sure what caused it in the first place, but I was hoping someone here might have seen it before and have an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tricked me, or I would have answered this much sooner. That's not an 'ER' symbol. ER = Entity Relation.

That symbol is from the relational diagram, which deals with tables and foreign keys vs entities and relations.

From the docs:
*Delete Rule: Action to take automatically when a row in the referenced table (in PK/UK Index) is deleted and rows with that value exist in the table containing this foreign key: NO ACTION (shown by a crossing line in diagrams) performs no action on these rows; **CASCADE (shown by an "X")** deletes these rows; SET NULL (shown by a small circle) sets null all columns in those rows that can be set to a null value; RESTRICT (also shown by one crossing line) prevents those rows from being deleted.*

[image]